scaleTime sets arbitrary tick count
I've created a timeScale using only 2 subsequent dates:
const xFn = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(parsedData, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width])
  .nice()

let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xFn);
xAxis.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d, %Y"));
xAxis.tickSize(8)

console.log("xFn.domain()"); 
console.log(xFn.domain()); // domain does have only w dates

It appears axisBottom has a brain of it's own, because it makes 8 ticks like shown in the picture:

The code above works fine for many data points, but it has issues when there is only a few.
I tried setting ticks explicitly with:
if(parsedData.length < 4) xAxis.ticks(parsedData.length);

Even with that, a domain with 2 subsequent dates still produces 3 x ticks as if xAxis.ticks is just a recommendation. What am I doing wrong?


Here's an answer I wrote 6 years ago about the same subject.  I won't close this question as a duplicate since so much time has passed (and many versions of d3) but I'm certain the situation is the same.  TLDR, the only way to force the ticks is to use .tickValues.

Mark’s comment is correct. When you construct a scaleTime with the extent of your dates, it doesn’t matter how many dates you have. It’s like you’re constructing an analogy, like “2000 is to 2020 as 0 is to 10”, from the domain to the range — but there could be a hundred points between 2000 and 2020, or none at all. d3.axisBottom doesn’t know anything about your data; it only knows the domain and range of your scale.
The number of ticks defaults to 10, and, as you discovered and as Mark said, the number you pass to ticks is merely a suggestion (see docs). If you only want ticks for the start and end dates:
let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xFn)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b %d, %Y"))
  .tickSize(8)
  .tickValues(d3.extent(parsedData, d => d.date))

Since you have .nice() on the scale, the start and end of the scale’s domain may be slightly different (rounded off to nicer values) than the extent of the dates in the data. So you can do either .tickValues(d3.extent(parsedData, d => d.date)) or .tickValues(xFn.domain()).
